# Совет на олимпиаду

Tags: php, mysql, олимпиада

Всем здравствуйте. Участвую в олимпиаде по php программированию, можете посоветовать, как лучше делать, чтобы жури понравилось? Один из критериев скорость работы скрипта. Я например любитель создавать классы, функции. Будет ли это плюсом? Что лучше использовать в mysql INNER JOIN или LEFT JOIN, COUNT или функцию mysql_num_rows? Ставить ли аппострофы в запросах? И главное: типы полей для БД указывать для чисел int(11), для небольших строчек varchar(255), для текстов TEXT?

**UPD:** УРАА, всем спасибо, 1е место на олимпиаде!!!

Comment: Олимпиада по php-программированию? Это что-то новенькое.


Если олимпиада классически связана с математическими задачами, то на код всем плевать - главное уложиться в отмеренное время выполнения для всех тестовых входных данных.

Comment: Есть один дальний малолетний родственник - РНРшник.

Оно не совсем олимпиада, скорее - конкурс. Мое пишет (удаленно, дома, после уроков) "Свой сайт на популярную тематику, который работает на своей CMS"

Библиотеки и фреймверки использовать запрещено (и JS-тоже).

Забавно будет подождать результатов.

Comment: Это олимпиада связана с реальными задачами. Это серьёзно, в 2012 году нужно было каталог магазина спрограммировать с сортировками и фильтрами + ещё куча всяких примочек. Т.ч. олимпиада интересная, + хороший приз. Хочу всё сделать круто. А то в сложных sql запросах могу напортачить...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Читать книги по РНР.

Потом снов читать книги, в перерывах - можно в общем по программированию.

Теперь по вопросам.

"любитель создавать классы, функции".

Функции создавать нужно. Если не создавать функции, то при объеме кода в 1-2К строк можно убится сразу.

Классы. Вообще, строго говоря личное наблюдение и мнение, классы в РНР сделаны криво и проект тормозят ощутимо. Если вместо объектного подхода использовать процедурно-линковочный (функции и require-модулей). Иногда быстрее получается в разы. Но так как у вас учебное задание и ляп у вас там будет много - можете писать и классы тоже. Так будет красиво, может кто оценит.

"INNER JOIN или LEFT JOIN"

Смотря какие данные нужны. 
LEFT JOIN выведет все строчки, даже есть в той таблице, которую join'ят их нет, а inner join только те, которые есть в обоих. Кстати есть ещё right join и просто join))

"COUNT или функцию mysql_num_rows"

По здравой логике count должен быть быстрее, там как идет подсчет индекса, а mysql_num_rows выгребает на гора кучу данных и пихает их в клиента. Но с php+mysql - всякое может быть)

Про типы полей - для начала да, а потом почитать [вот это](http://dimonchik.com/the-types-of-data-in-sql.html).

Comment: Про join'ы - http://www.anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-join

Comment: Спаасибо огромное) Книги по php не надо читать, будет доступ к мануалу) Задачку 2012 года решил без проблем, правда не на олимпиаде, а вот её щас выложили так для ознакомления. Поэтому вроде токо вопросы по sql, который я не учил, а на практике выучил при необзходимости))  вот книгу по sql надо бы)

Comment: Пробегитесь по статье - http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/phpintro очень-очень мало, но основные вещи.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону паттернов, это существенно ускорит процесс как разработки так и скорости. Далее прочитайте про стандарты программирования, Например: PSR 0, 1, 2, 3

Что касается базы данных, придерживайтесь минимум 3 нормальных форм ([Нормальная форма](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0))

И не забывайте про индексы в базе данных. Они значительно ускоряют процесс работы, правильно сконфигурированный сервер и вообще отлично.

[`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php)
и сразу читает, что пишут разработчики php красненьким

Comment: Вообще лучше использовать улучшеный модуль mysqli даже для запросов?

Comment: не могу сказать, никогда не использовал.